# How to pass parameters to a Snowflake query in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, snowflake

Where SQL Server is a data source, one can simply, write:

```
 SELECT name, age 
 FROM egTable
 WHERE age = @age
```

in the dataset query part of an SSRS report.

However, if your dataset is connected via ODBC to a snowflake data source, it behaves slightly different.
I have tried to do it as above and this way:

```
SELECT name, age 
FROM egTable
WHERE age = $age
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return an error, it behaves as though there is no parameter. Is anyone able to advice.

I am avoiding using filters (although they work) because of their efficiency issues, This question and response addresses that: [Which is more efficient, filtering the SSRS dataset or filter using a query parameter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96698/which-is-more-efficient-filtering-the-ssrs-dataset-or-filter-using-a-query-para)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can handle this.

### Use "?"

[Snowflake + SSRS Parameters](https://medium.com/@gabriel.mullen/snowflake-ssrs-parameters-a7bcc287fd07)

It will create a parameter "Parameter1" that you may rename and also map in the dataset properties.
`WHERE age = ?`

### Use expression in the dataset query

[Snowflake Forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D7Do0000006XtLKAU/detail?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00Di0000000hZh2&s1nid=0DB3100000001Fq&s1uid=0053r00000APiA2&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1695140776710)

- use expression
  `="SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '" + Parameters!Name.Value + "';"`
- Add fields manually

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/198559)

Comment: @mustaccio I have updated my comment, thanks.